# Unbinding and rebinding DataTables search event results in null sSearch

Tags: datatables

I'm in a bit of a pickle with this one. I'm using jQuery DataTables 1.10.6, and I want to make it so that when the user stops typing (like maybe after 950 ms?), the search is performed. I kind of have it working, but since I'm using server-side processing, sSearch (the search parameter) returns null.

I'm guessing it has to do with the unbinding and re-binding, but I don't know how to make it so that sSearch is sent properly.

```
var delay = function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    }
})();

$("div.dataTables_filter input").unbind();
$("div.dataTables_filter input").bind("keyup", function () {
    alert(this.value);
    delay(function () { 
        $("#MyTable").dataTable().fnFilter(this.value);}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a deprecated plugin which is a key debounce delay: https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnSetFilteringDelay

Even though it's stated that this won't work with 1.10+, there's a comment stating that a line change would allow it to work in 1.10+. So the following line:

```
anControl.unbind('keyup search input').bind('keyup search input', function() {
```

...would be replaced with:

```
anControl.off('keyup search input').on('keyup search input', function() {
```

I was also able to set the filtering delay timer in the calling argument. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables has an option to se delay, you can check it [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchDelay)

Comment: From what I understand though, searchDelay is only useful if you want to throttle, not debounce--meaning that searchDelay will only execute a draw once every n ms, whatever argument you provide it. I was looking for debouncing, to delay or restrict the call of the draw after a certain amount of time has passed (like no keypress after a certain amount of time).